# non HTTP response code - Amazon ELB

Tags: rest, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

My REST API returns non-standard HTTP response codes:
e.g. 40001, 40002.

It works just fine on local servers, however, when I need to serve them via Amazon ELB (Load Balancer) I get 502 error.

Is there a way to return non-standard HTTP response codes for servers running behind Amazon ELB?

Comment: Why would you design a REST API that operates over HTTP yet does not use correct HTTP response codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html#elb-listener-protocols

> Not all HTTP extensions are supported in the load balancer. You may
>   need to use a TCP listener if the load balancer is not able to
>   terminate the request due to unexpected methods, response codes, or
>   other non-standard HTTP 1.0/1.1 implementations.

So basically, if you want to use non-standard error codes you're probably going to have to go with a TCP listener.